# Laravel error: (1/1) ErrorException count(): Parameter must be an array or an object that implements Countable

Tags: laravel

I'm trying to update data from my website to the database but I have the error given in the title.

Part of my Controller:

```
 $user = auth()->user();
    $count = count($request->get('alt_rs','alt_ci','linkrs'));
    // On recupere les données de la BDD dans la variable $data
    for($i = 0 ; $i < $count ; $i++) {
        $data = [

            'nom' => $request->get('nom'),
            'prenom' => $request->get('prenom'),
            'date_de_naissance' => $request->get('date_de_naissance'),
            'job' => $request->get('job'),
            'adresse' => $request->get('address'),
            'code_postal' => $request->get('code_postal'),
            'ville' => $request->get('ville'),
            'telephone' => $request->get('phonenumber'),
            'accroche' => $request->get('accroche'),
            'email' => $request->get('email'),
            'permis_b' => $request->get('permis'),
            'photo_profil' => '../public/img/'. $filename,
            'password' => $request->get('password'),
            'logo_rs' => '../public/img/'. $filename,
            'logo_ci' => '../public/img/'. $filename,
            'description_ci' => $request->get('altci')[$i],
            'description_rs' => $request->get('altrs')[$i],
            'url' => $request->get('linkrs')[$i],
        ];
```

View example:

```
                                @foreach ($contact_info as $contact)
                            <label for="logo_rs">
                                    <input type="file" id="logo_rs" name="logo_rs[]" accept="image/png, image/jpeg" >
                            </label>
                            <label for="linkrs">
                                    <input type="text" placeholder="lien réseau social" name="linkrs[]" id="linkrs" value="{{$contact['url']}}">
                            </label>
                            <label for="altrs">
                                    <input type="text" name="altrs[]" placeholder="Descriptif" id="altrs" value="{{$contact['description_rs']}}">
                            </label>
                            <br>
                            @endforeach
```

What can I do to resolve this?

Comment: These screens have no marking to guide us. Please either add appropriate code or update the images with arrows or rectangles for better understanding.

Comment: sry im new in stack verflow, is that better ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `request->get('a','b','c')` you are using is not returning an array. Try putting all the data you need in an array before using the `count` function. Something like:

`$countable[] = request->get('a');`

The parameter of the `count()` function must be iterable (array,object)

Comment: the thing i dont understand is, i did the same thing in another controller and it worked well. i tried to do the exact same thing but it dosnt work..

The only difference is in usercontroller, im caling multiple inputs and counts at the same time

Answer (score 0):

Problem resolved i just had to choose one thing in $count

```
$count = count($request->get('alt_rs','alt_ci','linkrs'));

 became 

$count = count($request->get('linkrs'));
```